# How can I update the state of reducer?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, reducers

I want to update the state of activitiesData when ACTIVITIES_SEND_SUCCESS is executed by appending the new data to the end of the object activitiesData.

> ActivitiesReducer.js

```
import {
  ACTIVITIES_FETCH_SUCCESS,
  ACTIVITIES_SEND_SUCCESS,
  SUBACTIVITY_SEND_SUCCESS
} from '../actions/types';

const INITIAL_STATE = { activitiesData: {}, activityCreated: {}, listActivity: {} };

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ACTIVITIES_FETCH_SUCCESS:
      return { ...state, activitiesData: action.payload };
    case ACTIVITIES_SEND_SUCCESS:
      return { ...state, activityCreated: action.payload };
      case SUBACTIVITY_SEND_SUCCESS:
      return { ...state, listActivity: action.payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Comment: `appending the new data to the end of the object.` ? which object exactly

Comment: to the object activitiesData

Comment: Is activitisData an array or an object

Comment: activitisData is an object

Answer (score 0):

You can append the data using `spread operator syntax` like

```
export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ACTIVITIES_FETCH_SUCCESS:
      return { ...state, activitiesData: action.payload };
    case ACTIVITIES_SEND_SUCCESS:
      return { ...state, activityCreated: action.payload, activitiesData: {...state.activitesData, ...action.payload }  };
      case SUBACTIVITY_SEND_SUCCESS:
      return { ...state, listActivity: action.payload};
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Comment: it gives an error at the level of action.payload of activitiesData !!

Comment: Check the update, the error was because action.payload is not a valid key to object

Comment: It works this way return { ...state, activityCreated: action.payload, activitiesData: { ...state.activitesData, ...action.payload } }; however, for some reason the activitesData state is empty and only adds the recent data added !